# Get old style OpenGL code work in GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vertex-shader, vertex-array-object

I am trying to draw this pattern in OpenGL :

[image]

To get this, I created the pattern like :

```
vector< vector<DataPoint> > datas;
float Intensitytemp=0;
float xPos=0, yPos=0, angleInRadians=0;
for (float theta = 0.0f; theta < 4096; theta += 1.f)
{
    vector<DataPoint> temp;
    angleInRadians = 2 * M_PI*theta / 4096;
    for (float r = 0; r < 4096; r += 1.f)
    {
        xPos = cos(angleInRadians)*r / 4096;
        yPos = sin(angleInRadians)*r / 4096;
        Intensitytemp = ((float)((int)r % 256)) / 255;
        DataPoint dt;
        dt.x = xPos;
        dt.y = yPos;
        dt.Int = Intensitytemp;
        temp.push_back(dt);
    }
    datas.push_back(temp);
}
```

and I am drawing the pattern as :

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (int x = 0; x < 4096; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < 4096; y++)
        {
            xPos = datas[x][y].x;
            yPos = datas[x][y].y;
            Intensitytemp = datas[x][y].Int;
            glColor4f(0.0f, Intensitytemp, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(xPos, yPos, 0.0f);
        }
glEnd();
```

If I create the data in `glBegin()-glEnd()` block,it is working faster. But in both cases,I believe that  a better way is doing all in GLSL.I didn't understand the logic behind the modern OpenGL well.

I tried to create vertex buffer array and color arrays but could not get it work. The problem was not about transferring the arrays to graphics card.I am getting stackoverflows in arrays. *This is question of another topic* but here what I wonder is it possible to do this task in completely GLSL code *( those in .vert file )* without transferring these huge array to graphics card.

Comment: Could you please post code with problem? I think current code from questions is working well. But you have problem with porting this code to modern OpenGL. Am i correct?

Comment: yes you can do the whole thing in GLSL ... and from GL render just single QUAD covering the screen (does not matter if you use old or new style GL you can still use the GLSL compatibility profile limiting the newer stuff a lot but no need for it for this anyway). you just in fragment shader determine the distance from center point and use that for the color computation that is all no loop needed.

Comment: @Unick yes I am trying to do the things that code is doing correctly but slowly,in shaders. But I did not understand the loginc behind programming in shaders. As previous comment says , I can draw 4096x406 number of points without using loop in shader ,but how ?

Comment: See [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) for the init stuff and [2d raycasting effect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34708022/2521214) for how to do it just ignore the raycasting part and use just rest ... do you need shader example of your pattern generation?

Comment: @Spektre I have been told that using if s and for loops in shader should be avoided. Also I didn't get if the shader code is kinda parallelized automatically. Without sending any data (because I may not need), can I just do the drawing inside the main function of shader. Should I output something ,if so what ? 

Code example ,similar to mines, but not as complex as that in your tutorial, would really helps me.

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan added `if` less example ... btw your current implementation in **GL** is very bad containing too many unnecessary points,causing aliasing effects and slow downs. Why did you not use textures? You can render disc with 1D texture filling ... and generate the texture pattern on **CPU** side easily with single `for` loop ... Also generating in polar coordinates is not very good for rectangular filling you are doing (that is the cause of aliasing).

Comment: @Muhammet Ali Asan I think you need to understand how video cards and shaders works. After it you will be able solve your problem. I can recommend you one book: http://www.amazon.com/OpenGL-Shading-Language-Cookbook-Edition/dp/1782167021/ref=dp_ob_title_bk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **render quad covering the screen**

   ```
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   GLint id;
   glUseProgram(prog_id);

   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();

   glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   glColor3f(1,1,1);
   glVertex2f(-1.0,-1.0);
   glVertex2f(-1.0,+1.0);
   glVertex2f(+1.0,+1.0);
   glVertex2f(+1.0,-1.0);
   glEnd();

   glUseProgram(0);
   glFlush();
   SwapBuffers(hdc);
   ```

   Also see [See complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) on how to get **GLSL** working (even the new stuff)

   Do not forget to set your GL view to square area!
2. **in vertex shader pass the vertex coordinates to fragment**

   no need for matrices... the `pos` is in range `<-1.0,1.0>` which is fine for fragment.

   ```
   // Vertex
   varying vec2 pos;
   void main()
       {
       pos=gl_Vertex.xy;
       gl_Position=gl_Vertex;
       }
   ```
3. **in fragment compute distance from the middle `(0,0)` and compute final color from it**

   ```
   // Fragment
   varying vec2 pos;
   void main()
       {
       vec4 c=vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
       float r=length(pos);    // radius = distance to (0,0)
       if (r<=1.0)             // inside disc?
           {
           r=16.0*r;           // your range 16=4096/256
           c.g=r-floor(r);     // use only the fractional part ... %256
           }
       gl_FragColor=c;
       }
   ```

   Here the result:

   [image: example output]
4. **How GLSL works**

   You can handle the **fragment shader** as a color computation engine for polygon filling. It works like this:

   The **GL** primitive is passed by **GL** calls to **vertex shader** which is responsible for transformations and pre-computing of constants. **Vertex shader** is called for each `glVertex` call from oldstyle **GL**.

   If supported primitive (set by `glBegin` in oldstyle **GL**) is fully passed (like TRIANGLE,QUAD,...) the gfx card start rasterization. This is done by **HW** interpolators calling **fragment shader** for each "pixel" to fill. As the "pixel" contains much more data then just color and also can be discarted ... it is called **fragment** instead. Its sole purpose is to compute target color of the pixel on the screen it represents. You can not change its position only the color. That is the biggest difference between old **GL** and **GLSL** approach. You can not change the shape or position of objects only how are they colored/shaded hence the name **shaders**. So if you need to generate specific pattern or effect you usually render some primitive covering the area involved by **GL** and recolor it by computation inside mostly **fragment shader**.

   Obviously the **Vertex shader** is not called as often as **Fragment shader** in most cases so move as much of the computations as you can to the **Vertex shader** to improve performance.

   Newer **GLSL** versions support also geometry and **tesselation shaders** but that is a chapter on its own and not important for you now. (you need to get used to Vertex/Fragment first).

**[Notes]**

Single `if` in such simple shader is not a big problem. The main speed increase is just in that you pass single quad instead of `4096x4096` points. The Shader code is fully parallelized by the gfx **HW** directly. That is why the architecture is how is ... limiting some capabilities of what can be done efficiently inside shader in comparison to standard **CPU/MEM** architectures.

**[Edit1]**

You can often avoid the `if` by clever math tricks like this:

```
// Fragment
varying vec2 pos;
void main()
    {
    vec4 c=vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    float r=length(pos);            // radius = distance to (0,0)
    r*=max(1.0+floor(1.0-r),0.0);   // if (r>1.0) r=0.0;
    r*=16.0;                        // your range 16=4096/256
    c.g=r-floor(r);                 // use only the fractional part ... %256
    gl_FragColor=c;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### **To directly answer your question**

No, that's now how shaders work. Shaders redefine parts of the rendering pipeline. In ancient OpenGL, where the pipeline is fixed, the GPU uses built-in shader routines to render primitives you upload to it via the `glBegin/glEnd` related calls. With later OpenGL versions, however, you can write custom routines for your GPU to use. **In both cases**, *you need to send data for the shaders to work with.*

### To let you into a better approach on how to do it

First, a vertex shader feeds on vertices data. It takes vertices and operates on them one at a time applying various transformations (by multiplying the vertex by the model-view-projection matrices). Once it has done this for every vertex, the area made by connecting the vertices gets broken down into coordinate values (among other things you can pass from the vertex shader to the fragment shader) in a process called [rasterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation). These coordinates, each representing the location of a pixel on the screen, are then sent over to the fragment shader which operates on them to set the color and apply any lighting calculation.

Now, since what you're trying to draw is a pattern which has a formula behind it, you can color a 4096x4096 square, by sending only 4 vertices quite literally, as you wish to produce the same result.

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 150

in vec2 vertexPos;
out vec2 interpolatedVertexPos;

void main()
{
  interpolatedVertexPos = vertexPos;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 1.5

in vec2 interpolatedVertexPos;
out vec4 glFragColor;

void main()
{
  const vec2 center = vec2(2048, 2048);
  float distanceFromCenter = sqrt(pow((interpolatedVertexPos.x-center.x), 2) + pow((interpolatedVertexPos.y-center.y), 2));
  if (distanceFromCenter > 2048){
    discard;
  }
  float Intensitytemp = ((float)((int)distanceFromCenter % 256)) / 255;
  glFragColor = vec4(0, Intensitytemp , 0, 1);
}
```

Edit: I figured you may as well find this answer helpful:
[OpenGL big projects, VAO-s and more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720219/opengl-big-projects-vao-s-and-more/33721464#33721464)